# QGIS Slope Classification Issues

Tags: qgis, dem, raster-calculator, slope, reclassify

I am very new to QGIS for the primary purpose of creating a slopes layer so we know where slopes are above 15% or 20% or whatever we finally decide.

I have used our DEM to create a slope geotif and have used that to try and create a classified layer, but that is where my problems seem to begin. I used this formula to create my classified layer `((slope@1 < 15) OR (slope@1 > 60)) = 0` and while I get a new layer I am not able to view it, no matter how I manipulate the properites. I also tried to follow the [instructions](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/analysis_exercise.html) for the display that says to do this:

> 9.4.16. Setting the style for the reclassified layers
>
> - Open the Style tab in the layer’s Properties dialog as usual.
> - Under the heading Load min / max values from band, select the Actual    (slower) radio button.
> - Click the Load button.
>
> The Custom min / max values fields should now populate with 0 and 1,
>   respectively. (If they do not, then there was a mistake with your
>   reclassification of the data, and you will need to go over that part
>   again.)
>
> - Under the heading Contrast enhancement, set the Current dropdown list    to Stretch To MinMax.
> - Click OK.

I do not come up with the 0 and 1 that the instructions speak of (I am not using their tutorial data) but it seems that I should be able to see the layer.

Comment: Which values do you get? The raster created by our formula is binary. A cell can only be 0 or 1.

Comment: To follow along with @underdark's comment, it sounds like the step *before* (9.4.15) is where you have a problem. What are the values in your slope tiff? Are they integers between 0 and 100, or are they decimal between 0 and 1? If the latter, that formula is going to set your entire raster to 0 since all values are less than one (and therefore less than 15).

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest just to adjust the rendering styles of your DEM with Layer-Properties-Style. So no need to create new layers but you can play with colours on-the-fly. See the image below. Don't pay attention to labels, the values are what are used for classification. Classes 0-20, 20-30 and 30-40 are painted with colours, all above 40 is white. It is often fastest to get a usable sketch by doing preliminary classification with the "Classify" button and fine tune the result by adjusting class ranges and colours manually.

[image: DEM classified with QGIS]